# Can jackson determine root object type to deserialize to when json includes type property?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Assume serialization to json includes the class name of the actual object, using this annotation on the Class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
class MyClass {
    String foo;
}
```

So json is for example:

```
{"@type": "com.example.MyClass", "foo": "bar"}
```

Can this be deserialized without specifying the type? And I mean not even the super type. Just something like:

```
objectMapper.readValue(value, Object.class);
```

which doesn't actually work, it brings back a Map.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/30362446/873282

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it is certainly possible to do that although I have personally never used Jackson that way. You can deserialize it to a `JsonNode` object and then convert it to the proper type.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.foo = "bar";

// Serialize
final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);

// Deserialize
final JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);

// Get the @type
final String type = jsonNode.get("@type").asText();

// Create a Class-object
final Class<?> cls = Class.forName(type);

// And convert it
final Object o = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, cls);

System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

The output is:

> MyClass

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess that works. I was wondering if there was a more built-in way but I guess that wouldn't make any sense as Jackson could not possibly know how I have configured the JsonTypeInfo, without knowing the class. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

    MyClass original = new MyClass();
    original.foo = "hello";

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(original);
    MyClass foo = (MyClass) mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

This should work and is very convenient.

Comment: It works if you know the JSON represents `MyClass` at deserialization time. I took the question to refer to a scenario where you don't know the type of the object. That's the situation I'm currently trying to handle.

Comment: If you don't know the type, you can just assign to an object. The object.getClass() will tell you what type it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but there is a caveat: type you give MUST be something that includes `@JsonTypeInfo` you specify. `Object.class` will not have, unless you use "mix-in annotations" to associate it.

However, if you need to add type information for properties of (declared type of) `java.lang.Object`, you probably want to enable default typing: see `ObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(...)` for more information.
That will actually enable inclusion (and use) of type information for larger categories of classes, without need to add annotations.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).