# JsonNode to object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am writing a `JsonDeserialzer` for a POJO class `Attribute`:

```
public class AttributeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Attribute> {

        @Override
        public Attribute deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

            String name =  node.get("name").asText();

            //String value = node.get("value").asText();

            Attribute attr = new Attribute();
            attr.setName(name);
            attr.setValue(value);

            return attr;
        }
```

`Attribute` class has two variables `name` and `value` where name is `String` type and value is `Object` type.

I know to get the String value from `JsonNode` using

```
node.get("name").asText()
```

, but value being `Object` type it can be a List, String or anything.

How shall I create the `Attribute` object in the deserialzer ??

Attribute class:

```
public class Attribute {

    protected String name;
    protected Object value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: May be this answer to a previously asked question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/28384407/827204

Comment: Why do you want to implement the deserializer? Why not let Jackson's default?

Comment: @UriShalit: I am changing the name property's value, though it's not provided in the code above

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
  public class AttributeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Attribute> {

        @Override
        public Attribute deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

            String longName = getLongName(node.get("name").asText());
            System.out.println("Translated name: " + name);

            ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            ObjectNode o = (ObjectNode)node;
            o.put("name", name);

            Attribute attr = objMapper.convertValue(o, Attribute.class);

            return attr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only problem with this, is if the object you are deserializing also has special deserializion behaviour, you will miss them as you are using a new `ObjectMapper` - This can be solved in a similar matter to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson