# Fallback Class<?> for mapper.readValue

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am using Jackson for de/serialization in my app.

I have a situation where I need to convert a JSON string to one of my 3 classes. In case the string can't be converted to either one of 3 classes, it will considered to be an unrecognized case.

However, if the schema of json string and the provided class in `mapper.readValue(jsonString,MyClass1.class)` does not match, it throws an `UnrecognizedPropertyException`.

Currently I am using something like below, but it seems to be pretty messy.

```
try {
    obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass1.class);             
} catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException e1) {
    try {
        obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass2.class);
    } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException e2) {
        try {
            obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass3.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle unrecognized string
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle unrecognized string
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle unrecognized string
}
```

Is this how it needs to be done or is there any other alternative? Is there any way to configure the `mapper` to return `null` in case of unrecognized properties, as that would result in creating a simple series `if` blocks instead of nested `try-catch` blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method to do deserialization thing. this will return `null` on `UnrecognizedPropertyException`:

```
private <T> T deserialize(ObjectMapper mapper, Class<T> type, String jsonString) {
        T t = null;
        try {
            t = mapper.readValue(jsonString, type);
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException  e) {
            //handle unrecognized string
        }catch (IOException  e) {
            //handle under errors
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that configuring ignoring the unknown properties just create an empty instance of provided class via `Class<?>`, with default values, rather than creating `null` instance of the class. Hope this explanation is clear.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can create a generic method to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If `jsonString` is generated by you, you can consider to add `type info` and then use it to convert deserialized object. You could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384281/can-jackson-determine-root-object-type-to-deserialize-to-when-json-includes-type) for how to do it.

If `jsonString` is generated by other services beyond your control, then there's no type info you can get so you can only try it one by one, @Sachin Gupta's answer would be a nice choice.

I'd like to provide an additional option: define an `all-in-one` entity including all fields of `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3`, and make `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` be separated wrapper and only expose related fields for each. Code as follows:

Class `AllInOne`:

```
public class AllInOne {
    protected String a;
    protected String b;
    protected String c;

    public A asA() {
        return new A(this);
    }

    public B asB() {
        return new B(this);
    }

    public C asC() {
        return new C(this);
    }
}
```

Class `A`:

```
public class A {
    private AllInOne allInOne;

    public A(AllInOne allInOne) {
        this.allInOne = allInOne;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return allInOne.a;
    }
}
```

Class `B`:

```
public class B {
    private AllInOne allInOne;

    public B(AllInOne allInOne) {
        this.allInOne = allInOne;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return allInOne.b;
    }
}
```

Class `C`:

```
public class C {
    private AllInOne allInOne;

    public C(AllInOne allInOne) {
        this.allInOne = allInOne;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return allInOne.c;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        String jsonA = "{\"a\":\"a value\"}";
        String jsonB = "{\"b\":\"b value\"}";
        String jsonC = "{\"c\":\"c value\"}";

        needTypeA(om.readValue(jsonA, AllInOne.class).asA());
        needTypeB(om.readValue(jsonB, AllInOne.class).asB());
        needTypeC(om.readValue(jsonC, AllInOne.class).asC());
    }

    private static void needTypeA(A a) {
        System.out.println(a.getA());
    }

    private static void needTypeB(B b) {
        System.out.println(b.getB());
    }

    private static void needTypeC(C c) {
        System.out.println(c.getC());
    }
}
```

With implementation like this, we erased the specific type info at deserialization step, and bring it back at the moment we really need/use it. And as you can see there's not too much extra code, because what we actually did is just moving all fields declaration together, and added couple methods.

Notes:

- I declare fields in `AllInOne` to be `protected`, putting all POJO class in the same package will make `A`, `B` and `C` be able to access them directly, but not for other classes outside.
- Setting `om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);` to make jackson deserialize by `field`, so that we can remove duplicate `setter` and `getter` from `AllInOne` class
- If you do need to know the type info, you could add methods like `isA` inside `AllInOne` based on the fields info

Answer (score 0):

If json contains some define property, than you can try to use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`. Classes `MyClass1, ...` must implement this interface. Also I don`t remember exactly how to map unknown implementations to null.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, // level of define property
        property = <property_name>,
        visible = true,
        defaultImpl = NoClass.class)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = <interface-impl>.class, name = <property_value>)})
private <interface> value;
// getters and setters
```